# Distinct Count Index - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have simple table (MYSQL - MyISAM):

**EDIT: This is a 50M record table, adding a new index isn't really something we can do.**

```
actions (PRIMARY action_id, user_id, item_id, created_at)
```

Indicies:

```
action_id (action_id, PRIMARY)
user (user_id)
item_user (user_id, item)
created_user (user_id, created_at)
```

And the query:

```
SELECT count(distinct item_id) as c_c from actions where user_id = 1
```

The explain:

```
 1  SIMPLE  action  ref user_id,created_user    user_id 4   const   1415
```

This query takes around 7 seconds to run for users with over 1k entries. Any way to improve this?

I've tried the following and they are all worse:

```
SELECT count(*) from actions where user_id =1 group by item_id
SELECT count(item_id) from actions USE INDEX (item_user) where user_id = 1 group by item_Id
```

Comment: You can create a new Index?

Comment: It's to big of a tablet to create a new index - so I prefer to try find another way to do this without adding a new index. I would think all the correct indexes would already be there.

Comment: The `(user_id, item)` should have been picked up by the optimizer and used for this. Which version of MySQL are you using? Have you tried to `Force` the use of that index?

Comment: You can also try this query: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT NULL FROM actions WHERE user_id = 1 GROUP BY user_id, item_id) AS tmp;`

Comment: @ypercube If it force, it does full scan. 5.1 MySQL

Comment: Can you please add the `SHOW CREATE TABLE actions;` output in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Can you test the following:

```
SELECT count(*) as c_c 
   from (
       SELECT distinct item_id 
       from actions where user_id = 1
        ) as T1
```

Comment: This doesn't work - takes around 20 seconds to return users with > 1000 records.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using PHP, can you simplify your query to the following:

```
SELECT distinct item_id 
FROM actions 
WHERE user_id = 1
```

and then use `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of rows in your result?

Another option you could try, although it requires more work, is to:

1- **create another table** that will hold the total number of rows found for each `user_id`. meaning you'll have to create a table with two columns, one is the `user_id` and the 2nd is the `total` of items found in your previous table.

2- **schedule a job** to run ,every 1 hour for instance, and update the table with the total returned from the 'actions` table. At this point you can just query your newly created table like this:

```
SELECT total
FROM actions_total
WHERE user_id = 1
```

This will be much faster when you need your final result because you're dealing with a single row instead of thousands. The drawback here is that you may not get an accurate result depending on how ofter you need to run your job.

3- In case you decide not to use a job. You can actually still use the newly created table but you will need to update (increment/decrement) its total each time you insert/delete into the `actions' table.

N.B: Just trying to help